# Is it possible to intercept ICBMs?

Tags: warfare, weapon-mass-destruction

Assuming the Russians and Chinese launch all their 400+ ICBMs at the continental United States, how many could the US intercept with present-day technology?"

Comment: The basic problem is that it's a lot more expensive to shoot down an inbound than to build the missile in the first place.  It's an arms race the missile-builders win.  Interceptors have their use against rogue launches and countries like North Korea, building enough to counter a superpower simply isn't viable--they'll just build more birds.

Answer (score 1):

"Yes", "No", and "No".

The technology to [intercept ICBMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_%28missile%29) has existed for decades.

It was never fielded in numbers to intercept all of them, or even most.

[305 Russian missiles with 1166 warheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Missile_Troops#Numbers_of_missiles_and_warheads) are not going to remove every single American flag. China doesn't have enough to matter.

That should have been clear with simple googling and a look at wikipedia, and the tone of the question makes me wonder what you're really asking about. Voting to close.

Comment: how can I make this question more appropriate?

Comment: Keep the question about the Russian missile arsenal and American interceptors, without talk about airliners and accusations. Google the size of the Russian and Chinese forces so you don't have to guess (wrongly, I believe) how many Chinese missiles have the range to hit the US. "Assuming the Russians and Chinese launch all their 400+ ICBMs at the continental United States, how many could the US intercept with present-day technology?"

Comment: Some claims Russian and Chinese have 2400 icbm and US defense claims to be able to stop at most 20% of them in a controlled test is that true? My source is from quora.

Comment: The true numbers are probably secret, but I would think that there are no blatant breaches of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_START.

Comment: @user6760, you could read http://www.history.army.mil/html/books/bmd/BMDV2.pdf and http://www.rand.org/pubs/monographs/MG1075.html